# How to make new button Objects using a for loop and display it using javafx

Tags: java, for-loop, button, javafx

I am trying to display 9 buttons using javafx.

```
public class Main extends Application 
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {

        Button[] button = new Button[10];
        Pane pane = new Pane(); 

        for( int i=0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            button[i].setText("hi");
            button[i].setText("hi");
            button[i].setLayoutX(i*10);

            System.out.println(button[i].getText());
            pane.getChildren().addAll(button[i]);                   
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();       


}
```

Comment: How should the buttons be orientated? What should the Button's say on them, can you give us some more details, please?

Answer (score 2):

You create an `array` able to store `Button` element, but you never create the `Button` itself

So you have to do :

```
for( int i=0; i < 9; i++){
    button[i] = new Button();     // <-- here
    button[i].setText("hi");      // you have twice this line
    button[i].setLayoutX(i*10);

    System.out.println(button[i].getText());
    pane.getChildren().addAll(button[i]);                   
}
```

---

Also, if for other part you don't need to retrieve the `button` later, you don't need so store them and use an `array`, this will work :

```
for( int i=0; i < 9; i++){
    Button btn = new Button();     // <-- here
    btn.setText("hi");
    btn.setLayoutX(i*10);

    System.out.println(btn.getText());
    pane.getChildren().addAll(btn);                   
}
```